# 2006 Chevy cobalt speakers

Tags: chevrolet, speakers

My girlfriend just recently purchased a 2006 Chevrolet Cobalt from a co-worker. Everything seemed ok with it besides the stereo. No sound is coming out of any of the speakers at all. All functions work on the stock stereo and all displays work and every now and then when we start the car we will hear a slight sound out of the speakers. It's not just the front speakers it's the rear as well. I pulled the stereo out and all wires look connected so I'm at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?  This is a bit broad.  Please provide any troubleshooting you have already done.  Anything additional would be helpful in assisting you with your problem.  Welcome to the site, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that you actually have speakers in the car. If the previous owner upgraded the speakers, he may have removed them before selling you the car.
2. Make sure the speakers are connected. You pulled the stereo to verify there are speaker wires plugged into the back of it, check the other end.
3. Check the settings on the stereo (balance and fade): the stereo may be set to use a speaker that doesn't exist or that doesn't work.
4. Make sure the speakers actually work by removing them and connecting them to the stereo in another vehicle.
5. Make sure the stereo actually works by connecting it to speakers from another vehicle. Basically, remove a speaker from another vehicle and connect it to this one.

Comment: Ok so I've pulled the main stereo unit and I've seen all wires are there and all attached. When I pulled the trim to get to the back of the stereo I turned the car on and heard some white noise so I'm sure there are speakers there. I'm gonna pull the door panels next to see if there is a loose connection to the speakers but that still wouldn't explain while all 4 don't work. I'll update as soon as I can

Comment: Maybe the radio anti-theft code needs to be entered. Or the memory back up wire fuse is blown. See if the owner manual has any info on it. Those are other things you can check. I assume it is a stock radio?